# Error NU1202 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.0 package is not compatible with net50

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone help me with this error?

Error NU1202 The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.0 package is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework, Version = v5.0). The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.0 package supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard, Version = v2.1)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Microsoft.eShopWeb.Infrastructure</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.EFCore.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.Specification" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.Specification.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.8.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ApplicationCore\ApplicationCore.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\Migrations\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I have downloaded the required SDK package with the [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks), .net framework developer pack [download-link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework), and installed them. **Restart the server**, then the build is successful.

Check your dotnet version with `dotnet --info`